# PyTorch and OpenCV not working in same python

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, anaconda

OpenCV and PyTorch can not be imported with the same python version.

I have installed Pytorch through anaconda and OpenCV from source build .so both can not be imported at the same time:

```
somnath@somnath-Inspiron-5558:~/LaneDetection/lanedet$ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
>>> exit()
```

```
somnath@somnath-Inspiron-5558:~/LaneDetection/lanedet$ conda activate
(base) somnath@somnath-Inspiron-5558:~/LaneDetection/lanedet$ python3
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 19:59:22) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you specify the correct options to cmake when building for your specific conda env.

1. Activate your conda env `conda activate <name>`
2. Install numpy with `conda install numpy`
3. Run `cmake` from the `build` directory using these options:

```
cmake \
        -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<your choice> \
        -D BUILD_opencv_python2=0 \
        -D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib/libpython3.9.so \
        -D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=${CONDA_PREFIX}/include/python3.9/ \
        -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=${CONDA_PREFIX}/bin/python \
        -D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib/python3.9/site-packages \
        <path to opencv source>
```

`CONDA_PREFIX` contains the directory of the currently active environment., change `python3.9` in case you have another python version.

Comment: Great, make sure to accept the answer to mark that it solved your question